# Angularjs 1.x -- UIRouter Path /XYZ vs /#!/XYZ

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a path variable at the top level. For eg: website.com/XYZ123 where XYZ123 is some account code. How can I do that in an angular app?

My Config below:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    .state ('/', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'views/landing.html',
          controller: 'landingCtrl',
          authenticate: false
      }).state ('signin', {
          url: '/{accountCode:[0-9A-Z]{6}}',
          templateUrl: 'views/student/signin.html',
          controller: 'studentSigninCtrl',
          authenticate: false
      })
```

website.com/#!/XYZ123 -- works.. but what can I do to make website.com/XYZ123 also go to the angularjs SPA?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: Thank You so much for pointing me in the right direction and the prompt reply @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

In a `config` block in your main module, you could use `$locationProvider` to turn off HTML5 mode and not display the hash in the route:

```
// Removes the fragment identifier ('#') from urls
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Note there are some caveats of doing this, mainly you need to make sure you include a `<base>` tag in your main (index) HTML file:

```
<head>
    <base href="/"/>
</head>
```

For documented references, see [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider).

Comment: I did.. It works great as long as I am within the app. But when I hit the browser refresh button I get Cannot GET /3R2YA2

Comment: I am going to host this app on s3/cloudfront on aws so I am not sure if I need to change something so bookmarks etc would work on my app. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AliceWaterland, I think you need to understand what happens when you "refresh" an AngularJS SPA application.